# PHP page not redirecting anymore

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm writing a PHP site wherein the user enters his password in PHPPage1 and it get's submitted as POST to PHPPage2 for validation. I needed PHPPage2 to pop-up an error box for invalid password and when the user clicks the OK button of that alert box then the page redirects to PHPPage1.

My code is below, the problem is, for invalid password, the page displays the alert box but does not redirect to PHPPage1. Actually it look's like it continues to read the rest of the script on PHPPage2 instead of redirecting.

Please note that I added `error_reporting(0);` to let you know it's there so you can tell me if that is causing the issue. I know I shouldn't be using it since it hides any errors it detected. Also note that this script works before and redirects to PHPPage1, it's only when I added the `<script>` for alert box that I started getting this issue. I needed an alert box instead of just an echo. Can you tell what is wrong with this code, I thought it should be working.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

//Validate user
if ($_POST['Password'] != "Servermaster")
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The password " . $_POST['Password'] . " is unknown.');</script>";
    header("Location: http://stackoverflow.com/");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Try `('The password "' . $_POST['Password'] . '" is unknown.')` if that doesn't work, try a regular `alert()`. If that works, then you'll know where the problem is; inside the present alert.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a `Headers already sent` error? Try commenting out the `echo`. @Fred-ii- - I think that might cause more issues as you'll have unescaped `"`s.

Comment: @Joe he possibly has the `display_errors=off` in php.ini

Comment: @baldrs - yeah, I think that's it. (I +1'd you)

Comment: using `Location` is a stupid idea there. Send valid HTML page and js redirect `window.location = 'URL';`

Comment: @Deadooshka that is what sessions are for, to store data between requests.

Comment: Just as an aside, never simply alert that a password is incorrect as this informs a potential hacker that the username is valid. Use 'invalid username or password' instead.

Comment: @TheBlueDog so the idea of sending output _BEFORE_ redirect is not wrong, how do you think?

Comment: Thanks Fred, but I'm getting Parse Error when I do that instead. Hmm, `error_reporting(0);` isn't working either because it still showed/echoed the parse error message, dang it!

Comment: @baldrs: Of course it's incorrect, that wasn't my point though... Read the words in front of you - **Just as an aside**.

Comment: I know, I made an error on that quote method. My bad.

Comment: Sorry guys, I failed to inform you that this website will not ask for username, just password. The URL and all will not be shared publicly anyway, this is jut for about 7 specific users in the office. And no, I have not modified anything in my php.ini or .htaacess as I am a beginner in PHP and wouldn't want to do anything too complicated for me right now.

Comment: `Location` means immediate redirect, despite the content

Comment: This works `header( "refresh:1;url=http://www.google.com/" );` while using `ob_start();` at the top. Otherwise, you will get a headers sent error.

Comment: @user3613603: Without a username, it's not only 7 specific users in the office, it's **every** user in the office that got the password from another. You should revisit your login security philosophy.

Comment: Thanks Blue Dog, I know what you are trying to say but I can assure you, this page goes through a lot of stages before getting to this part and this part only requires a pass code and each of the users have unique ones. Do you have any suggestions about my goal though?

Comment: Did you not read [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857633/php-page-not-redirecting-anymore#comment36718863_23857633) ? @user3613603 this works; for me anyway.

Comment: Hi Fred, I think I understand what's wrong now, I guess by doing an echo, I am reactivating or tapping PHPPage2 so the header or even `window.history.back();` won't work anymore. But I will try your suggestion as soon as I get more info on `ob_start()`

Comment: The `window.history.back();` could probably be used in an `else` statement. Plus, as stated below, sessions would be more suited for something like this as well as being more transportable throughout multiple pages and with multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect after you sent output. Turn on error_reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', true)` and you will see an error report. Comment out the echo line and it will work.

Comment: Yes, if I comment out the echo, the redirect will work. That echo wasn't there before, I added it since I wanted the page to display an alert box before redirecting. So this is not possible? I did a lot of research before posting here, and for this purpose, the only method I can find is doing the echo and using header location script to go back

Comment: @user3613603 Is the page you intend redirect is on the same server? If so, use the sessions(http://ua1.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Thanks Baldrs, will try that too. I am also looking for other ways and checking on `window.history.back();`. Yes both pages are in the same server